# Apache and Sqlite3 issue

Tags: apache, sqlite, freebsd

I'm using ports only on this server. After restarting apache I got "segment fault (core dumped)" message. But apache is started at least... httpd-error.log shows this:

```
profiling:/usr/ports/databases/sqlite3/work/sqlite-3.7.3/.libs/sqlite3.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/usr/ports/databases/sqlite3/work/sqlite-3.7.3/.libs/sqlite3.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/usr/ports/databases/sqlite3/work/sqlite-3.7.3/.libs/sqlite3.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/usr/ports/databases/sqlite3/work/sqlite-3.7.3/.libs/sqlite3.gcda:Cannot open
```

Listing of that dir:

```
baccy# ls  /usr/ports/databases/sqlite3/work/sqlite-3.7.3/.libs/
libsqlite3.a    libsqlite3.la   libsqlite3.lai  libsqlite3.so   libsqlite3.so.8 sqlite3         sqlite3.gcno    sqlite3.o
```

On this system I've got redmine installed, that's why sqlite is included in here.. now I installed django and I need sqlite3 so much..

It would be nice to know, WHY this error appears, and HOW to handle this =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an answer

it's GCONV param fault... just go to /usr/ports/databases/sqlite3 and then make config, and remove GCONV param.